# Why does a new default directory have user executable permissions where as a new file only has user read and write permissions?

Tags: unix, permissions, directory

Noticed this when creating a new directory in unix, and was just curious as to why this is so.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new directory created by a user and owned by the user with full permissions is no big deal.  However, a new file/program if executed accidentally or before configuration could have catastrophic results.  So the designers decided to give you a layer of protection.

It also prevents other users from executing the file unless you specifically grant permission.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need the executable permissions to naviguate into the directory.

So basic permissions allow user to read file (read file permission), and to access file in directory (directory execute permission).

Note that read permission on a folder allow user to list files in it. (But doesnt allow to read them unless execute permission is granted too as I said in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, +x on a directory means that the user can 'execute it' hence change into it (replace user by group or other depending on position in permissions).

Hence `drwxr--r--` means only user can change into directory. More [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Permissions).

Answer (score 1):

The directory needs to have executable permissions so you can do things such as cd into it. Also the executable permission lets you look into the directory for inode information of the files it contains.

More info can be found at this [source](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/AUnix1/FilePermissions.htm).